# Generic unmodifiableList

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections, unmodifiable

I wrote:

```
this.array = (X[]) Array.newInstance(init.getClass(), size);

// ...

public List<X> get()  {        
    return Collections.<X>unmodifiableList(this.array);
}
```

But I get the error:

> unmodifiableList in Collections cannot be applied to (X[])

How can I create a generic unmodifiable list?

Comment: `return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());`

Comment: @Lino You mean `Collections.emptyList()`?

Comment: @shmosel as I read again the comment I've written, it seems quite wrong to me, as OP probably has a populated array and not an empty one. But if he does want to return an empty list your approach is better

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it like this:

```
public List<X> get()
{
    List<X> modifiableList = Arrays.asList( this.array );
    return Collections.unmodifiableList( modifiableList );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public List<X> get()  {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(this.array));
}
```

Comment: The first option won't work as there is no ArrayList constructor that accepts array. The second one though is correct

Comment: Cool, it is now fully correct answer even though it makes it identical to a second answer.